# What package is tail included with?

Tags: tail

What package is tail (the command-line tool to see the end lines of a file) included with in the latest stable version of Ubuntu, if I want to install or uninstall it (and does it come installed by default)?

I already have it installed; I just don't remember if I installed it or it was already there. I made a program that requires it as a dependency (so that's why I ask).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `dpkg -S` suggests it's from `coreutils`

```
anwar@anwarpc:~$ dpkg -S $(which tail)
coreutils: /usr/bin/tail
```

Also check `dpkg -L`

```
anwar@anwarpc:~$ dpkg -L coreutils | grep tail
/usr/bin/tail
/usr/share/man/man1/tail.1.gz
```

`coreutils` comes pre-installed, so it was already there. As the name suggests, those are *core* to any linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

On my newly installed (stable) Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 I have it by default in version 8.26 :

```
$ tail --version
    tail (GNU coreutils) 8.26
    Copyright © 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+ : GNU GPL version 3 ou ultérieure
    <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    C'est logiciel libre, vous êtes libre de le modifier et de le redistribuer.
    Ce logiciel n'est accompagné d'ABSOLUMENT AUCUNE GARANTIE, dans les limites
    autorisées par la loi applicable.

    Écrit par Paul Rubin, David MacKenzie, Ian Lance Taylor
    et Jim Meyering.
```