# tail: not found on a Chroot Directory, how i enable it?

Tags: command-line, tail

I'm really a noob on Ubuntu, I'm facing a simple problem that I don't find anywhere, I follow this tutorial to make an ssh jail directory

https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/

I know that the user will not have some commands but I want to enable some to the user, in this tutorial have these commands to enable this :

```
# cp -v /bin/ls /home/test/bin/
# cp -v /bin/date /home/test/bin/
# cp -v /bin/mkdir /home/test/bin/
```

and there is too find the libraries for this commands :

```
ldd /bin/ls
# cp -v /lib64/{libselinux.so.1,libcap.so.2,libacl.so.1,libc.so.6,libpcre.so.1,libdl.so.2,ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,libattr.so.1,libpthread.so.0} /home/test/lib64/
```

I managed to make this commands work successfully but the "tail" command I try everything but nothing is working.

I use the `ldd /bin/tailf` **( tailf is the command? )**

it displays some libraries I use the cp command and is not working, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu, the command `tail` is located in `/usr/bin/tail` ( see also [package information from related post](https://askubuntu.com/a/905015/295286) ), so you want to do

```
ldd /usr/bin/tail
```

Note that in addition to copying the commands, you should either link or copy some of `/lib` directories, since some of the binaries rely on shared libraries stored there, in particular `/bin/sh` relies on that.  See also: [Change /bin/sh link temporarily](https://askubuntu.com/a/1074369/295286)

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but, my ubuntu is version 16.0.4 i dont have this file in bin/tail Just bin/tailf why?

Comment: @user3515184  Well, that is strange. Ubuntu and its official "flavors" ship with  `/usr/bin/tail` because it's from a standard package. The `tailf` is like `tail -f`, it's supposed to keep reading the file as new lines are added to it. As for why you only have `/bin/tailf`, I have no clue. Perhaps you have installed a modified Ubuntu or if you are using the system provided by a hosting service, then the sysadmins could have modified the Ubuntu image.

Comment: I must create a folder called /usr/ and put it in the folder?

Like /home/jail/usr/bin/tail or just /home/jail/bin/tail? and the libraries

Comment: @user3515184 Well, have you found `tail` yet ? If yes, make folder `/home/jail/usr/bin` and copy it there

Comment: thank you very much Sergiy, I'm found the tail and now is working fine. I'm glad that have people like you.

Comment: @wavrik You're welcome. I'm glad to help.